# Video player that can quickly refresh videos and supports many formats

Tags: video, animation, video-player, video-production

I am new to making videos, and I've started making a video animation library for Node JS. Basically, I have an output video which I update really often, and I need a player to quickly watch the video.

I am using an old Windows 7 computer. Most videos I'm playing are less than 5 seconds long and are 24fps.

I need a video player that can play most video formats without taking much CPU, with the ability quickly refresh to show latest mp4 file.

Chrome doesnt work. It is too slow to reload a chrome tab, and sometimes it still shows the old version of a video after I change the file.

Windows media player doesn't work because it is too slow, no way to quickly refresh, and has trouble playing videos with partially transparent pixels.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Have you tried VLC?

Comment: I've heard of it, but I've never personally used it. Is it easy refreshing videos?